# Is there another way to call cleanUp() of the TourGuide Library?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use this library https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide ,

currently it works fine but as i found out that `.cleanUp()` should be called in the buttons `onClickListener`,

just wondering if there's any workaround to be used to call it..

in my situation i have 4 buttons, and the `onclick` is setted in the `xml` file,.

```
public void myAction(View v){

    mTourGuideHandler.cleanUp();//<--- my attempt
    if(v.getId() == R.id.first){
     //do something
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.second){
     //do something
    }
}
```

the code above is what im trying to do.. but no success, is there any work around or suggestive ways to call `cleanUp()` except inside the `setOnClickListener()`?

Comment: you want to cleaup tour without clicking button?isn't it?

Comment: not completely without clicking... my method is called when one of the buttons are clicked...

Comment: Are you sure myAction method is called when you click any button?

Comment: i guess the buttonevent is not properly bind with the activity. check that first.
otherwise define button inside activity and define onClick event and remove onClick from xml

Comment: yes it is working..  i recently found this https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide/issues/2 and i think it is the only way to call the method..